# How to return zero for a missing monomial in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to return zero for a missing monomial but could not find any pointers in sympy's documentation. My intention is to build a sparse array from a number of expressions. Is there an easy way to do this?
MWE:

```
import sympy
x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x, y, z')
func_1 = 3 + x + 5 * y + 2 * z
func_2 = 1 + x + 2 * y

expr_2 = [func_1, func_2]
func_vars = [x, y, z]

eqs = sympy.parallel_poly_from_expr(expr_2, func_vars)
[[eqn.coeff_monomial(m) for m in eqn.monoms()][:-1] for eqn in eqs[0]]

# >>> [[1, 5, 2], [1, 2]]
# expected [[1,5,2],[1,2,0]]
```

Updated MWE using indexedbase with a nonlinear variable based on smichr's suggestions:

```
def get_coeffs(coeff_dict, func_vars):
    c = coeff_dict
    for i in list(c.keys()):
        b, _ = i.as_base_exp()
        if b == i:
            continue
        if b in c:
            raise ValueError('multiple generators with %s' % b)
        if any(k.has(b) for k in c):
            raise ValueError('cross terms detected with %s' % b)
        c[b] = c[i]  

    return [coeff_dict[val] for val in func_vars]  


x =  sympy.IndexedBase('x')
func_1 = 3 + x[0]**2 + 5 * x[1] + 2 * x[2]
func_2 = 1 + x[0] + 2 * x[1]

expr_2 = [func_1, func_2]
func_vars = [x[0], x[1], x[2]]


([get_coeffs(i.as_coefficients_dict(), func_vars) for i in expr_2])
# I get [[1, 5, 2], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: I note that your polynomials are linear in the three generators which suggests that you do not really want to use polynomials at all (maybe take a step back and explain why you want to use polnyomials at all). If you do want to use polynomials then how would you decide in general when there are nontrivial monomials like `x**2*y` what the entries in the output list should be?

Comment: Basically I am trying to reproduce the output of Mathematica's 'CoefficientArrays' function which gives the arrays of coefficients of the variables vars in the polynomials polys. It gives a list containing SparseArray objects. It also says For nonlinear equations, the m[i] are not unique. CoefficientArrays by default assigns nonzero coefficients only to monomials where the variables appear in the same order as vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with linear equations then the `linear_eq_to_matrix` can work on the raw (non-Poly) expressions to give you a matrix of the coefficients:

```
>>> linear_eq_to_matrix([i.as_expr() for i in eqs[0]],[x,y,z])
(Matrix([
[1, 5, 2],
[1, 2, 0]]), Matrix([
[-3],
[-1]]))
```

The `as_coefficients_dict` method might be a better bet. And if you have powers of some variable then the resulting dictionary can be modified to store the bases of the powers with the same coefficient.

```
>>> x=IndexedBase('x')
>>> eq=3 + x[0]**2 + 5 * x[1] + 2 * x[2]
>>> eq.as_coefficients_dict()
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 3, x[0]**2: 1, x[2]: 2, x[1]: 5})
>>> c=_
>>> for i in list(c.keys()):
...   c[i.as_base_exp()[0]] = c[i]  # set values bases of powers
...
>>> [_[x[i]] for i in range(4)]  # default dict will supply 0
[1, 5, 2, 0]
```

Comment: This is similar to what I want but it throws an error for example "Expecting a Symbol but got x[0]" when I make 'x' IndexedBase and use x[0], x[1], x[2] instead of x, y, z. The approach I used still works in this scenario but the linear_eq_to_matrix function throws an error. Any suggesstion on how to deal with such a case?

Comment: `symeqs = Tuple(*eqs[0]).xreplace(reps)` where `reps = dict(zip((x[0], x[1], ....), numbered_symbols('s')))` then feed `symeqs` and `list(reps.values())` to `linear_eq_to_matrix`.

Comment: I tried it on a more complex linear equation and it worked.

Comment: Hello smichr, I thought I should ask if there was a way to use this approach even when I have a nonlinear term such as x[0]**2, such that it disregards the nonlinearity and still returns the coefficient of 3 + x[0]**2 + 5 * x[1] + 2 * x[2] as 1

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Hello Smichr, thanks for the updated answer. It seems like a more robust approach to create the sparse matrix from a list of coefficients irrespective of whether there are nonlinear terms. I defined a function from your answer that accepts the defaultdict and list of coefficients as args.

Comment: You might want to confirm that all terms are univariate monomials: `all(len(t.freee_symbols) < 2 for t in Add.make_args(expr))`. If so, then the "linear" variables are those as the keys other than 1 in the `as_coefficients_dict` result.

Comment: I have added to my MWE above. at what point in the code do I confirm could you please update your answer based on my updated question so I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: I modified the MWE to check for cases like `3*x + 2*x**2` (multiple generators) and `3*x + 3*x**2*y` (cross terms).

Comment: hello Smichr I am afraid there is one more final condition I am finding it hard to implement. Mathematica returns [1 , 1,  2] for "3+(1+x)*x + y+2z" but returns 0 for ''3+x^2 + y+2z''. It seems to be able to differentiate both situations. How do I add this condition in your updated code?

Comment: `from sympy.core.function import _mexpand`...`_mexpand(i).as_coefficients_dict()...`. `_mexpand` will give you a flat expression without nesting.

Comment: absolutely!!!. that was function I needed. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a normal list, you can just post-process it. To pad a 2D list `x` with `0`s on the right side, you can just do this:

```py
width = max(map(len, x))
for row in x:
    row.extend([0] * (width - len(row)))
```

Basically, you get the width of the whole thing by finding the maximum width of all of the rows. Then, for each row, you just insert however many `0`s are needed after it to get it to the right width.